# Artifactory sends wrong reset password URL

Tags: reverse-proxy, httpd, artifactory

When a user uses the "Forgot password", they are sent a URL to the reset-password page in Artifactory.
In our case the URL contains an extra /ui, like this

```
https://external-hostname/ui/ui/auth/reset-password?key=
```

Once removed the URL works perfectly. I've searched the settings, but can't find anything that can change that.

We have a reverse Apache httpd proxy in front of the Artifactory instance, so perhaps I did something wrong there?

```
ProxyPreserveHost on
AllowEncodedSlashes On

<Location /artifactory>
    RequestHeader set Host external-hostname
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port 443
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
    RequestHeader set X-JFrog-Override-Base-Url https://external-hostname/

    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /
    ProxyPass http://192.168.1.2:8081/artifactory
    ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.1.2:8081/artifactory
    Require all granted
</Location>

<Location /ui>
    RequestHeader set Host external-hostname
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port 443
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
    RequestHeader set X-JFrog-Override-Base-Url https://external-hostname/

    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /
    ProxyPass http://192.168.1.2:8082/ui
    ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.1.2:8082/ui
    Require all granted
</Location>
```

The external-hostname is shared with other applications, so I'm unable to map "/", hence the explicit mapping of "/ui

Comment: Maybe you need to adjust the `Artifactory URL` in the e-mail settings: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF6X/Mail+Server+Configuration and/or https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/General+System+Settings and remove the unnecessary `/ui`  there.

Comment: Oh, boy, do I feel stupid,, the extra /ui was in the artifactory URL in the mail settings.
Thank you very much.